# Public bitcoin node accessible to web code?

Tags: nodes

I want to connect to the bitcoin network and broadcast a transaction.

I can't run my own bitcoin node on localhost because I'm in php on a web server (shared host), is there an internet-accessible open-to-the-public trusted reliable well-known node I can use?

Even blockchain.info api requires a local service to be running, so that won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that using Bitcoin-core. What you can do as an alternative is using electrum servers.

You can find all the information about using it and commands in [here](https://electrumx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/protocol-basics.html).

Features:

- Broadcast transactions.
- Getting legacy address transactions, unspent and balance.
- Free and public and there are many available peers.
- open source (python).

If you want to get segwit address balance, transactions.. you should convert it to script hash first.

Note: using third party APIs & servers are less secure than running a self-hosted full node. It's recommended to avoid third-parties when you deal with money.

Comment: I'm in php on a shared web server. Wouldn't this solution require me to have a private virtual server, at least?

Comment: Never, if you have Bitcoin-core you should get VPS, Electrum size is just 20MB, don't forget to open port 50002, 50003

Comment: I can't open a port. I can't install software. I don't "have" bitcoin core or anything else, just php files and html pages. I'm on a shared web server. Either I don't understand what you are suggesting or your answer isn't a suitable answer b/c it is disregarding my code environment. Maybe I don't understand then? When I look at your link, it wants me to install some software on the server, correct?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice your comment. You can get another server and install electrumx on it, or you can use other people server since its public and you don't need to open those ports though.